# Copyright of Stack Overflow Trends

Tags: support, legal, trends

I would like to use some of the graphs from Stack Overflow Trends in my academic research. I am unable to find any copyright information regarding that data. Is it legal to use it with proper references?

Comment: The data used for these graphs is readily available, license terms are described in [this blog post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/04/stack-overflow-creative-commons-data-dump/).

Comment: The Trends tool does *not* include deleted questions.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Legal use of Stack Overflow content and licensing can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#licensing).

Set plainly, yes, if it contains proper referencing, and is for noncommercial use.

Stack Overflow holds all rights to all material posted on Stack Overflow, and all material hosted themselves.

> Stack Overflow Content
>
> All materials displayed or performed on the public Network, including
>   but not limited to text, graphics, logos, tools, photographs, images,
>   illustrations, software or source code, audio and video, and
>   animations (collectively “Network Content”) (other than Network
>   Content posted by individual “Subscriber Content”) are the property of
>   Stack Overflow and/or third parties and are protected by United States
>   and international copyright laws (“Stack Overflow Content”).
>
> The Stack Overflow API shall be used solely pursuant to the terms of
>   the API Terms of Use.
>
> All trademarks, service marks, and trade names are proprietary to
>   Stack Overflow and/or third parties and use of the Network means you
>   agree to abide by all copyright notices, information, and restrictions
>   contained in any Network Content accessed through the Services.
>
> The Network is protected by copyright as a collective work and/or
>   compilation, pursuant to U.S. copyright laws, international covenants,
>   and other copyright laws. Other than as expressly set forth in these
>   Public Network Terms, you may not copy, modify, publish, transmit,
>   upload, participate in the transfer or sale of, reproduce (except as
>   provided in this Agreement), create derivative works based on,
>   distribute, perform, display, or in any way exploit any of the Network
>   Content, software, materials, or Services in whole or in part. You may
>   download or copy the public Network Content, and other items displayed
>   on the public Network for download or personal use provided that you
>   maintain all copyright and other notices contained in such Public
>   Content.
>
> From time to time, Stack Overflow may make available compilations of
>   all the Subscriber Content on the public Network (the “Creative
>   Commons Data Dump”). The Creative Commons Data Dump is licensed under
>   the Creative Commons CC-BY-SA license. By downloading the Creative
>   Commons Data Dump, you agree to be bound by the terms of that license.
>
> Any other downloading, copying, or storing of any public Network
>   Content (other than Subscriber Content or content made available via
>   the Stack Overflow API) for other than personal, noncommercial use is
>   expressly prohibited without prior written permission from Stack
>   Overflow or from the copyright holder identified in the copyright
>   notice per the Creative Commons License. In the event you download
>   software from the public Network (other than Subscriber Content or
>   content made available by the Stack Overflow API) the software
>   including any files, images incorporated in or generated by the
>   software, the data accompanying the software (collectively, the
>   “Software”) is licensed to you by Stack Overflow or third party
>   licensors for your personal, noncommercial use, and no title to the
>   Software shall transfer to you. Stack Overflow or third party
>   licensors retain full and complete title to the Software and all
>   intellectual property rights therein.